# How to design dynamo db datase when heavy iteration of data is needed?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-aurora

Please don't mark it as duplicate I have done enough research before asking this question.

How to design a dynamo DB database if I need to iterate through the data in my dynamo db, now the first problem is 1mb limit imposed by dynamodb, I can deal with it by finding out last key and then start from that last key again but as stated by documentation dynamodb's scan operation is quite heavy operation.

The second problem is dynamo DB does not support auto increment so I have to maintain an id to successfully iterate through my collection which means a lot of overhead for ex- if i have to delete an item to have to change the id of all subsequent items.

The third problem is how can I count the no of items in my dynamo db one solution is to use a separate table for maintaining count and update it accordingly but that's just another overhead

my question is what is the better architecture and approach to design a database in which i want to iterate through all the collection is dynamo db really a right fit for such use case or i should move to aws aurora.

Comment: On autoinc: it's almost certainly the case that you don't need, and should not try to implement, auto-increment fields - use UUIDs, for example. You should never have to modify N-1 records to correct IDs simply because you deleted one record and its ID (this is true for *any* database). On scan: if you genuinely need to scan through the entire table (do you?) then I don't see how you can avoid doing a scan. The fact that you have to make multiple requests with continuation markers is not too onerous.

Comment: thanks for the quick response @jarmod but how would i iterate through data then if the uuid is not sequential

Comment: If the ordering of rows is important then your primary or secondary index should contain a relevant field e.g. a  timestamp. If you need rows retrieved strictly in insertion order then you're going to have to fabricate some kind of insertion ID or timestamp - that could be a number you store in a second table and you perform atomic increments/updates against it. However, to my mind, this is not really ideal and a regular SQL database might be more appropriate.

Comment: i got your point @jarmod however my usecase  is pretty common and if dynamo db is not a right choice then can you point me in some direction for what type of use cases is dynamodb is appropriate choice.

Comment: You've stated a strong requirement for scanning an entire table, presumably repeatedly. Is this a large table (millions of rows)? Why are you scanning through the entire table?

Comment: @varnit you stated your usecase is pretty common, but I've never heard of anyone using a database in this way before. You usually create queries that return only the records you need, instead of continuously iterating through every record sequentially, over and over. That is not a common use case for databases at all. It almost sounds like you might be better off using something like Redis if you just want fast in-memory access of your data in sequential insertion order, instead of any sort of query capability.

Comment: i want to do something equivalent to select * from table; in sql isn't is a common use case